# Adding an Event for Espresso on Wordpress from C#

Tags: wordpress

Working with WordPress and the Espresso Plugin for Events.  I've never dealt with WP or Plugin's before, so I'm in new territory.

I am attempting to add an event and I keep getting the following error:

`{"code":"rest_cannot_create_events","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create events. Missing permissions: ee_edit_events,ee_edit_others_events,ee_edit_private_events","data":{"status":403}}`

I've gone into the WP admin pages and made sure the user I am trying to login as has all the permissions for this plugin.

The first thing I do is access the /wp-login.php page to get the Cookies:

```
        string formVars = "";
        string result = "";
        string eventUrl = $"<url>/wp-login.php";
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        formVars = $"log={UserName}&pwd={Password}";

        Cookie = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

        AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        result = PerformPost(eventUrl, formVars, true, headers);
```

The PerformPost uses an HttpWebRequest to send and receive.

That part seems to work and I get what looks like valid cookies.

I then do another post to /wp-json/ee/v4.8.29/events/ and pass in the body just the name of the event like EVT_name=TestEvent.

It's at this point that I get the the error mentioned above.

So a couple of questions.

1) Has anyone done this before? (Added an Event to Espresso on WordPress)

2) If Espresso doesn't like what I am feeding it, does it generate this error rather than just telling me I'm not giving it the correct information?

I've also tried using the Basic Auth plugin with the same results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.